# Mahapps TextBox ClearTextButton missing when add style

Tags: wpf, styles, mahapps.metro

So this is my controller:

```
<TextBox 
    Width="398"
    Height="25"
    Margin="23,0,0,0"
    >
    <TextBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" >
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gainsboro"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton" Value="True"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,1,0,0" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    <Setter Property="Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton" Value="True"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBox.Style>
</TextBox>
```

As you can see i added `Property="Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton" Value="True"` but still i cannot see this `Buttons` unlen i removed all `Triggers` and add this inside the controller:

```
<TextBox 
    Width="398"
    Height="25"
    Margin="23,0,0,0"
    Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton="True">
</TextBox>
```

Comment: This question is probably what you are looking for:
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32230427/extending-textbox-in-wpf-using-mahapps-keeping-style

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should base your `Style` on the "MetroTextBox" `Style`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource MetroTextBox}" >
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Gainsboro"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
    <Setter Property="Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton" Value="True"/>
    <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,1,0,0" />
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="Controls:TextBoxHelper.ClearTextButton" Value="True"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Or the implicit one:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}" >
...
```

Comment: in later versions: `BasedOn="{StaticResource MahApps.Styles.TextBox}"`