# WPF TextBox Extension unable to use MahApps TextBoxHelper

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, mahapps.metro

I have an extended wpf textbox and I would like to use MahApps TextBoxHelper to add a watermark. Using regular textboxes worked just fine but as soon as I tried to replace them with my extended textbox `TouchTextBox` the watermarks disappeared along with the Metro style. My extended textbox is designed to work with a custom touch keyboard and it has a number of events geared toward handling this feature:

XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Class="MyNamespaceHERE.TouchTextBox"
     xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
     xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
     xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
     xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
     xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
     xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyNamespaceHERE"
     mc:Ignorable="d" 
     GotFocus="TouchTextBox_GotFocus"
     LostFocus="TouchTextBox_LostFocus">
</TextBox>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class TouchTextBox : TextBox
{

    public TouchTextBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void TouchTextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StaticEvents.OnShowTouchKeyboard(sender, e);
        StaticEvents.TouchKeyboardKeyTouch += StaticEvents_TouchKeyboardKeyTouch;
        StaticEvents.TouchKeyboardSpaceTouch += StaticEvents_TouchKeyboardSpaceTouch;
        StaticEvents.TouchKeyboardBackspaceTouch += StaticEvents_TouchKeyboardBackspaceTouch;
    }

    private void StaticEvents_TouchKeyboardBackspaceTouch(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = CaretIndex;
        if (CaretIndex == 0) return;
        Text = Text.Remove(CaretIndex - 1, 1);
        CaretIndex = i - 1;
    }

    private void StaticEvents_TouchKeyboardSpaceTouch(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = CaretIndex;
        Text = Text.Insert(CaretIndex, " ");
        CaretIndex = i + 1;
    }

    private void StaticEvents_TouchKeyboardKeyTouch(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = CaretIndex;
        string t = (sender as Button).Content.ToString();
        Text = Text.Insert(CaretIndex, t);
        CaretIndex = i + 1;
    }

    private void TouchTextBox_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StaticEvents.OnHideTouchKeyboard(sender, e);
        StaticEvents.TouchKeyboardKeyTouch -= StaticEvents_TouchKeyboardKeyTouch;
        StaticEvents.TouchKeyboardSpaceTouch -= StaticEvents_TouchKeyboardSpaceTouch;
        StaticEvents.TouchKeyboardBackspaceTouch -= StaticEvents_TouchKeyboardBackspaceTouch;
    }
}
```

I followed the advice I found in this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32230427/extending-textbox-in-wpf-using-mahapps-keeping-style) but so far it has not solved the issue. According to the solution, I need to add a style that is based on TextBox, so here is what I have in my Resource Dictionary:

```
<Style TargetType="local:TouchTextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBox}}" x:Key="TouchTextBoxStyle"/>
```

I added this style to each instance of my TouchTextBox controls so that they look like this:

```
<local:TouchTextBox x:Name="UsernameTextBox" Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Username" Width="200" Text="{Binding Username}" Style="{StaticResource TouchTextBoxStyle}"/>
<local:TouchTextBox x:Name="PasswordTextBox" Controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="Password" Width="200" Margin="0,30,0,0" Text="{Binding Password}" Style="{StaticResource TouchTextBoxStyle}"/>
```

So far no luck. How can I get back all the great features of MahApps' TextBoxHelper with my custom TouchTextBox user control? I really appreciate any guidance you can provide.

Edit:

I took Joel Lucsy's advice and implemented a `TouchTextBoxHelper` class to handle the `DependencyProperty` for my event handling:

```
public class TouchTextBoxHelper : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsTouchKeyboardTargetProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("IsTouchKeyboardTarget", typeof(bool), typeof(TouchTextBoxHelper), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, IsTouchKeyboardTargetChanged));


    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(TextBox))]
    public static bool GetIsTouchKeyboardTargetEnabled(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(IsTouchKeyboardTargetProperty);
    }

    [AttachedPropertyBrowsableForType(typeof(TextBox))]
    public static void SetIsTouchKeyboardTargetEnabled(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsTouchKeyboardTargetProperty, value);
        TextBox tb = obj as TextBox;
        if (tb == null) return;
        if (value)
        {

            tb.GotFocus += TextBoxBaseGotFocus;
            tb.LostFocus += TextBoxBaseLostFocus;
        }
        else
        {
            tb.GotFocus -= TextBoxBaseGotFocus;
            tb.LostFocus -= TextBoxBaseLostFocus;
        }
    }

    private static void IsTouchKeyboardTargetChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tb = d as TextBox;
        if (null == tb)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("The property 'IsTouchKeyboardTarget' may only be set on TextBox elements.");
        }

        if (e.OldValue != e.NewValue)
        {
            //tb.SetValue(SpellCheck.IsEnabledProperty, (bool)e.NewValue);
            if ((bool)e.NewValue)
            {
                tb.GotFocus += TextBoxBaseGotFocus;
                tb.LostFocus += TextBoxBaseLostFocus;
            }
            else
            {
                tb.GotFocus -= TextBoxBaseGotFocus;
                tb.LostFocus -= TextBoxBaseLostFocus;
            }
        }
    }

    private static void TextBoxBaseGotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TouchTextBoxEvents.tb = sender as TextBox;
        StaticEvents.OnShowTouchKeyboard(sender, e);
        StaticEvents.TouchKeyboardKeyTouch += TouchTextBoxEvents.StaticEvents_TouchKeyboardKeyTouch;
        StaticEvents.TouchKeyboardSpaceTouch += TouchTextBoxEvents.StaticEvents_TouchKeyboardSpaceTouch;
        StaticEvents.TouchKeyboardBackspaceTouch += TouchTextBoxEvents.StaticEvents_TouchKeyboardBackspaceTouch;
    }

    private static void TextBoxBaseLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StaticEvents.OnHideTouchKeyboard(sender, e);
        StaticEvents.TouchKeyboardKeyTouch -= TouchTextBoxEvents.StaticEvents_TouchKeyboardKeyTouch;
        StaticEvents.TouchKeyboardSpaceTouch -= TouchTextBoxEvents.StaticEvents_TouchKeyboardSpaceTouch;
        StaticEvents.TouchKeyboardBackspaceTouch -= TouchTextBoxEvents.StaticEvents_TouchKeyboardBackspaceTouch;
    }
}

public class TouchTextBoxEvents
{
    public static TextBox tb = null;
    public static void StaticEvents_TouchKeyboardKeyTouch(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = tb.CaretIndex;
        string t = (sender as Button).Content.ToString();
        tb.Text = tb.Text.Insert(tb.CaretIndex, t);
        tb.CaretIndex = i + 1;
    }

    public static void StaticEvents_TouchKeyboardBackspaceTouch(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = tb.CaretIndex;
        if (tb.CaretIndex == 0) return;
        tb.Text = tb.Text.Remove(tb.CaretIndex - 1, 1);
        tb.CaretIndex = i - 1;
    }

    public static void StaticEvents_TouchKeyboardSpaceTouch(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i = tb.CaretIndex;
        tb.Text = tb.Text.Insert(tb.CaretIndex, " ");
        tb.CaretIndex = i + 1;
    }
}
```

It's kind of horifying but it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than creating a custom control, you should create a DependencyProperty similar to the way the TextBoxHelper does to add your events into a normal TextBox. This would eliminate the need for the style as well.

Comment: Sounds good, where would I add DependencyProperties? Can you give some resources or examples?

Comment: Check out https://wpf.2000things.com/tag/dependency-properties/ and https://wpftutorial.net/DependencyProperties.html and just for reference, the TextBoxHelper source is at https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/develop/src/MahApps.Metro/MahApps.Metro.Shared/Controls/Helper/TextBoxHelper.cs

Comment: Thanks for your help Joel! It took some doing and I don't know if this is the "best" way to do it, but I have implemented my own TouchTextBoxHelper!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add this `Attached Properties` to the `TextBox` to show the WaterMark.

```
controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="My Watermark" 
controls:TextBoxHelper.UseFloatingWatermark="True" // If Needed.
```

Full code with `TextBox`.

```
<TextBox Height="40" Width="125" MaxLength="15"  
    controls:TextBoxHelper.Watermark="My Watermark" 
    controls:TextBoxHelper.UseFloatingWatermark="True"/>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have the actually done just this with each instance of my TouchTextBoxes. I've edited the post to include the instances of TouchTextBox.

Comment: The problem is that while TextBoxHelper works with regular text boxes, it breaks when I try to use my custom TouchTextBox control.

Comment: There is no error, my Watermarks just disappeared when I changed from TextBox to my TouchTextBox.